# i want the data to be save sucessfully

Tags: java

I have a JFrame name opinion. in this form I have given a error message for each field means whenever I am filling the form and if I put any field empty and than click save button it should display that error message for that perticular empty field is empty. my code is saving the data but when I put any field empty and click on save button it shoowing the error msg that perticular field is empty but when I click on ok button of that error msg box it also saving the data but with that empty field my code is:

```
    String name= (String)cbNM.getSelectedItem();
    if(name.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE NAME");

    String socialservice=(String)cbsocial.getSelectedItem();
    if(socialservice.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," SELECT THE SOCIAL SERVICE");

    String whichservice=tasocial.getText();
    if(whichservice.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER SOCIAL SERVICE U LIKE");

    String expectation=taexpectation.getText();
    if(expectation.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER UR EXPECTATION FROM WANI SAMAJ");

    String revealinfo=(String)cbreveal.getSelectedItem();
    if(revealinfo.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SELECT UR DECISION ON REVEAL THE INFORMATION");

    String addr=taaddress.getText();
    if(addr.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE ADDRESS");



    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String qry= "INSERT INTO Opinion(PersonName,LikeSocialService,WhichService,Expectation,RevealInformation,Address) VALUES('"+name+"','"+socialservice+"','"+whichservice+"','"+expectation+"','"+revealinfo+"','"+addr+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(qry);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS SAVED SUCCESSFULLY ");
        con.close();

    } catch(SQLException eM) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS NOT SAVED");
    } catch(Exception et) {
        System.out.println("error:"+et.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Two tips  1) Don't SHOUT at your end users.  2) Avoid kiddie style words like 'U' & 'UR'.  They don't impress anyone worth impressing, they just make you seem a buffoon.

Answer (score 2):

After you show the message, your method continue to run because you didn't break the run in any step:

```
if(name.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE NAME");
```

The basic solution (though pretty ugly) is to add `return` after message appears:

```
if(name.equals(""))
{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE NAME");
        return;
}
```

A better solution is to create an array of the JTextAreas (I guess that's what the prefix `ta` stands for) and an array of the CheckBox / RadioButtons and iterate them. For example:

At init or GUI building:

```
String    tainputnames[] = {"Social Service", "Expectation", "Address"};
JTextArea tainput[] = new JTextArea[tainputnames.length];
for (int i=0; i < tainputnames.length; i++)
{
    tainput[i] = new JTextArea("");
    tainput[i].setName(tainputnames[i]);
}
```

---

At the check:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tainputnames.length; i++)
{
    if (tainput[i].getText().equals("")
    {
        OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter " + tainputnames[i]);
        return;
    }
}
```

---

the same for check boxes etc.

Comment: +1 for the loop example/explanation, though I don't know that he's really ready for that yet :)

Comment: @Brian - I understood that in the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not stopping it from doing so:

```
if(whichservice.equals(""))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER SOCIAL SERVICE U LIKE");
```

Once the call to `showMessageDialog()` returns you let it continue down to your code that saves it in the database.

```
if(whichservice.equals(""))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER SOCIAL SERVICE U LIKE");
    return;
}
```

Or, you could restructure your code to be a series of if/else if with the code that saves to the database being contained in a final `else` at the end.